# Demonstrate the following sequence is Cauchy sequence...

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Here I have such an exercise:

Show that the sequence $(x_n)$,where

[image]

is a Cauchy sequence.

Here's the solution:
[image]

Can you, please, take a look and explain me why the relation marked with $"?"$ is true, and why is it necessary? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_{n+p}-x_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n+p} a_k-\sum_{k=0}^na_k=$$

$$=a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_n+\ldots+a_{n+p}-(a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_n)=a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\ldots+a_{n+p}$$

It's necessary to do this as **this is** Cauchy's condition.

Answer (score 1):

Let us write $C_k$ for the members $\displaystyle\frac{\cos(k\alpha)}{2^k}$, then we have
$$\begin{align} x_n &=C_0+C_1+\dots+C_n \\ 
x_{n+p} &= C_0+C_1+\dots+C_n+C_{n+1}+\dots+C_{n+p}
\end{align}\,.$$
Thus, $x_{n+p}-x_n=C_{n+1}+\dots+C_{n+p}\ $ (and actually we get strict *equation* instead of $\le$).